# adb / mdb debugger in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

Is there a way of calling debugger commands from a shell script?

I have a script that loops through a directory with core dumps. I want to run the command adb on each core dump and then quit adb so the bash script can keep running. This is what I have..

```
for f in $CORE_DIR/*
do 
    echo "$f details" >> ${TEMP_RESULT_FILE}
    adb $f >> ${TEMP_RESULT_FILE}
    #this is where i need to run the adb exit command which is $q
done
```

I need a way to run the $q adb command from the script. At the moment the script hangs until I type $q and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know adb/mdb, and currently don't have any solaris access to try it out, but something like this *may* work:

```
for f in $CORE_DIR/*
do 
    echo "$f details" >> ${TEMP_RESULT_FILE}
    adb $f << EOF >> ${TEMP_RESULT_FILE}
myadbcommand     # run your adb command
\$q              # quit adb
EOF

done
```

If adb reads its commands from stdin, then this should work.  The `{command} << EOF`<kbd>newline</kbd>`{lines of input}`<kbd>newline</kbd>`EOF` construct is a [bash here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Oops yes.  I escaped the `$q` in case there *are* variables that should expanded in the adb command.

Comment: `echo "::command" | mdb $file` is also commonly used when you just want to execute a single line of mdb commands and then exit.

Comment: Alanc that is exactly what I was looking for. it worked exactly like I wanted. thank you.
Thanks to everyone for taking the time to help! Appreciate it